Quarkus logger does not use the logger name
I've created a simple hello world applicaiton to test logging with quarkus. I've noticed that the @LoggerName does not seem to work as inteded
I've created a class
package org.acme.customlogger;

import org.jboss.logging.Logger;

import io.quarkus.arc.log.LoggerName;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;

@ApplicationScoped
public class MyCustomLogger {

    @LoggerName("foo.bar.logger")
    Logger logger;

    @Inject
    Logger log; 


    public void log() {
        logger.info("loggername");
        log.info("regular inject");
    }
}

and a test
package org.acme;

import org.acme.customlogger.MyCustomLogger;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTest;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;


@QuarkusTest
public class CustomLoggerTest {

    @Inject
    MyCustomLogger myCustomLogger;

    @Test
    public void quarkus_log_test() {
        myCustomLogger.log();

    }
    
}

in the test i'm seeing the output
Oct 12, 2024 10:48:33 AM org.acme.customlogger.MyCustomLogger log
INFO: loggername
Oct 12, 2024 10:48:33 AM org.acme.customlogger.MyCustomLogger log
INFO: regular inject

which is not expected, i would assume foo.bar.logger would be used instead of org.acme.customlogger.MyCustomLogger for the line INFO: loggername
Here is my pom file so you can see versions
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>code-with-quarkus</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <compiler-plugin.version>3.13.0</compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.release>21</maven.compiler.release>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
        <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus.platform</quarkus.platform.group-id>
        <quarkus.platform.version>3.15.1</quarkus.platform.version>
        <skipITs>true</skipITs>
        <surefire-plugin.version>3.3.1</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-rest-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                            <goal>native-image-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parameters>true</parameters>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                        <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>native</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <skipITs>false</skipITs>
                <quarkus.native.enabled>true</quarkus.native.enabled>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>

I've tried setting the category in application.properties. These are the only settings in my application.properties
quarkus.log.level=DEBUG
quarkus.log.category."foo.bar.logger".level=DEBUG

but this should not be needed according too
https://quarkus.io/guides/logging
Testing base on comments
If i add quarkus.log.category."foo.bar.logger".level=ERROR i still see both log messages
oct 12, 2024 7:52:50 PM org.acme.customlogger.MyCustomLogger log
INFO: loggername
Oct 12, 2024 7:52:50 PM org.acme.customlogger.MyCustomLogger log
INFO: regular inject


It is quite possible that what you're seeing is not the logger category, but the name of the calling class. Do you have any custom configuration for logging format? What you're showing doesn't look like the default Quarkus format; in fact, it looks like the default JUL format, which suggests that perhaps JBoss LogManager is not used at all.

Yes that is the fully qualified class name. I had the following format
quarkus.log.console.format=%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%c{2.}] (%t) %s%e%n
i've now deleted it but it looks the same

Oct 12, 2024 1:01:40 PM org.acme.customlogger.MyCustomLogger log
INFO: loggername
Oct 12, 2024 1:01:40 PM org.acme.customlogger.MyCustomLogger log
INFO: regular inject


these are the logs after deleting it. i'll update the post with full application.properties.
is there anyway i can verify which logger is used or set the logger?

Try changing the last property to quarkus.log.category."foo.bar.logger".level=ERROR. The "loggername" entry should then no longer show up.

so i've added quarkus.log.category."foo.bar.logger".level=ERROR to my application.properties but i still see both log message
Oct 12, 2024 7:52:50 PM org.acme.customlogger.MyCustomLogger log
INFO: loggername
Oct 12, 2024 7:52:50 PM org.acme.customlogger.MyCustomLogger log
INFO: regular inject

Try printing the logger.getName(). It seems weird: I have the exact same code and it works perfectly fine.
